# SendKeys.Send Keyboard shortcuts

Tags: c#, controls, keyboard-shortcuts, sendkeys, alt

I want to send a Keyboard shortcut using sendkeys.send. I know that it's possible to send keys like backspace and arrow keys, but I'm not sure about control and alt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> To specify keys combined with any
>   combination of the <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>, and
>   <kbd>ALT</kbd> keys, precede the key code with
>   one or more of the following codes:
>
> <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>  <kbd>+</kbd> 
>   <kbd>CTRL</kbd>   <kbd>^</kbd>  
>   <kbd>ALT</kbd>    <kbd>%</kbd>

Ref: [SendKeys.Send Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send.aspx)